# On Querying Genres.Members.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI for albums

Tags: java, android, mediastore

I'm interested in performing a query for all of the albums from a particular genre. Android makes it easy to perform a similar query for the albums from a particular artist by using `MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums.getContentUri`, but as far as querying genres goes, `MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri` is the best provided way, but this is used to return the songs from a genre.

You can easily return the album names for each member of a genre after performing the `Genres.Members` query and then using `MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.ALBUM`, to return album names, but again this is useful only if you're showing the songs.

Is there some sort of selection I could make to return only the albums from a genre, or perhaps a special `Uri` I could use? I haven't found any docs on this, so if anyone has any information it would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you are:

```
    {
        int genreId = 2; // << Set Your Genre ID Here
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.getContentUri("external");
        Log.i("XXX", "uri = " + uri.toString());
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {

            String selection = "album_info._id IN "
                    + "(SELECT (audio_meta.album_id) album_id FROM audio_meta, audio_genres_map "
                    + "WHERE audio_genres_map.audio_id=audio_meta._id AND audio_genres_map.genre_id=?)";
            String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(genreId) };
            String[] proj = { AlbumColumns.ALBUM };
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, selection,
                    selectionArgs, null);
            if (null != cursor) {
                Log.i("XXX", "cursor rows count = " + cursor.getCount());
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    Log.i("XXX", "  Album: " + cursor.getString(0));
                }
                cursor.close();
                Log.i("XXX", "cursor closed");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("XXX", "Error Querying Database");
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

*Edit* 
 Query fixed to get all albums with specified genre Id

Comment: Thanks, ra. I'm curious about how you had the answer. Are you just familiar with `MediaStore` and SQL? Did you look at any docs?

Comment: it is my first deal with mediastore at all, how? take a look to http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java, the rest is easy.